# An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven': Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: bazel

When i add the command

```
maven_install_json = "//:maven_install.json"
```

and when i run

```
bazel run @maven//:pin or bazel run @unpinned_maven//:pin"
```

I'm getting the below issue

```
Repository maven instantiated at:
  C:/users/myil.s/ideaprojects/bazeltestverification/WORKSPACE:15:14: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/myil.s/_bazel_myil.s/dcwwy5pe/external/rules_jvm_external/defs.bzl:130:30: in maven_install
Repository rule pinned_coursier_fetch defined at:
  C:/users/myil.s/_bazel_myil.s/dcwwy5pe/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl:983:40: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: C:/users/myil.s/_bazel_myil.s/dcwwy5pe/external/rules_jvm_external/third_party/bazel_json/lib/json_parser.bzl:672:18: JSON parsing failed. None
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/myil.s/_bazel_myil.s/dcwwy5pe/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl", line 335, column 13, in _pinned_coursier_fetch_impl
                fail("Failed to parse %s. Is this file valid JSON? The file may have been corrupted." % repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr.maven_insta
ll_json) +
Error in fail: Failed to parse C:/users/myil.s/ideaprojects/bazeltestverification/maven_install.json. Is this file valid JSON? The file may have been corru
pted.Consider regenerating maven_install.json with the following steps:
  1. Remove the maven_install_json attribute from your `maven_install` declaration for `@maven`.
  2. Regenerate `maven_install.json` by running the command: bazel run @maven//:pin  3. Add `maven_install_json = "//:maven_install.json"` into your `maven
_install` declaration.
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/myil.s/_bazel_myil.s/dcwwy5pe/external/rules_jvm_external/coursier.bzl", line 335, column 13, in _pinned_coursier_fetch_impl
                fail("Failed to parse %s. Is this file valid JSON? The file may have been corrupted." % repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr.maven_insta
ll_json) +
Error in fail: Failed to parse C:/users/myil.s/ideaprojects/bazeltestverification/maven_install.json. Is this file valid JSON? The file may have been corru
pted.Consider regenerating maven_install.json with the following steps:
  1. Remove the maven_install_json attribute from your `maven_install` declaration for `@maven`.
  2. Regenerate `maven_install.json` by running the command: bazel run @maven//:pin  3. Add `maven_install_json = "//:maven_install.json"` into your `maven
_install` declaration.
ERROR: no such package '@maven//': Failed to parse C:/users/myil.s/ideaprojects/bazeltestverification/maven_install.json. Is this file valid JSON? The file
 may have been corrupted.Consider regenerating maven_install.json with the following steps:
  1. Remove the maven_install_json attribute from your `maven_install` declaration for `@maven`.
  2. Regenerate `maven_install.json` by running the command: bazel run @maven//:pin  3. Add `maven_install_json = "//:maven_install.json"` into your `maven
_install` declaration.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.153s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Comment: I think you may have an error of some type in the "maven_install.json" file, try pasting it into a json formatter and it will tell you if its valid json or not.